# OnNetworkError (#282) Requires extended permission share item

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, extjs

I am using Sencha Touch 2 + Android + PhoneGap + GetSocialize SDK. I try to share something on Facebook using getsocialize sdk. I already made an example on android without PhoneGap and it works very well without error. When I used PhoneGap + sencha I get this error:

```
282 Requires extended permission share item
```

I know I have given `publish_stream share_item` permissions to my facebook app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [282 requires extended permission share item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851242/282-requires-extended-permission-share-item)

Comment: That one's already closed, and this one is in English and cleaned up, so let's give this one a chance to get answered